# AWK: Compare two columns conditionally in one file

Tags: awk

I have a pipe `(|)` delimited file where `$1` has IDs and there are values in `$2` and `$3`. The file has ~5000 rows in it with each ID `$1` repeated multiple times. The file looks like this

```
a|1|2
a|2|0
a|3|3
a|4|0
b|5|3
b|2|4
```

I am trying to print lines where the $2 on the current line is <= the max $3 so the output will be

```
a|1|2
a|2|0
a|3|3
b|2|4
```

Any lead on this would be highly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to, for each `$1`, print those lines where `$2` is less than or equal to the max `$3`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[|]" }
NR==FNR {
    max[$1] = ( ($1 in max) && (max[$1] > $3) ? max[$1] : $3 )
    next
}
$2 <= max[$1]
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file file
a|1|2
a|2|0
a|3|3
b|2|4
```

Comment: Hi Ed Morton! Thank you very much for this. I am fairly new to awk scripting so could you please explain what the script is doing. Also, how can I convert it to one-liner (sorry!)

Comment: You're welcome. It's pretty simple so please think about it, read the man page, and add print statements to dump variables if you aren't sure of anything and then ask specific questions if you have them about any part of it that's still unclear and I'll be happy to answer them. Why do you want to covert it to a one-liner?

Comment: Ok. I will read the man page. Thank you very much for your time and help. Much appreciated!

Comment: Sounds good and if you do have any specific questions later about any parts of it please do feel free to ask.

Comment: Ok. So I saved this as .awk script and ran it using `awk -f tst.awk file` on my file but it does not give me any output and that is the reason I wanted to convert it to one-liner. I think I am making some mistake while coping and pasting it to a script. Thanks.

Comment: You made a mistake calling it. I'm doing `awk -f tst.awk file file` while you did `awk -f tst.awk file` (so it'd only read `file` once instead of twice). You need a 2-pass approach for this - first to figure out the max $3 and then to use it in the comparisons with each $2.